# C# richtextbox data clipped while reading from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am writing a C# program which could continuously take data from the serial port and immediately display it on the rich text box of WPF. The problem is that when I use the below code, the first bit of every HEX value is clipped and I get an output like 
 (Say)

```
B 3C 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F
```

Instead of getting

```
0B 3C FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF.
```

Why is this happening and what mistake I am making?
I have checked with Terminal software and the data that I am receiving is correct. It is only while displaying in my program where it clips the first bit.

Also how do I separate the first 2 and the last 2 bytes and stop it from being displayed on the richtextbox.
 The code is below:

```
 string received_data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
char[] store_char_array = received_data.ToCharArray();
string display_text = "" ;
foreach (var i in store_char_array)
      {
         string hex_value = String.Format("{0:X}", Convert.ToUInt32(i));
  display_text += hex_value + " ";

 }

Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(display_text)));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the {0:X2} format string instead.  And use Read(), not ReadExisting() so you get bytes instead of a string.

Comment: Thankyou for your Patience! but replacing it with read() gives a stream of 0s.

Comment: You can assume there's a bug in Read() or a bug in your code.  Knowing where to look first takes time and experience, you only get that from spending the time.

Comment: Ok! this has defied all my logic! sp.readexisting() works smoothly and Shows the correct result in the richtext box until the Most significant bit (the 8th bit) is 1. when the 8th bit is 1 the 4 lower significant bits turn into 1111 (F) and the 4 higher significant bits turn to 0011(3). so if i have for example 7E, it is displayed correctly in the richtextbox BUT if it is 8A or 9E (or any Byte with MSB as 1) then the richtextbox always Displays 3F. The data is correct as when i use readbyte, everything works perfectly and the richtextbox Shows correct result but it is slower.

Comment: has anyone got any idea why the sp.readexisting is behaving like this?

Comment: There's just no point in asking a question if you don't follow the advice you get.  ReadExisting() returns a string, not bytes like Read() does.  It converts the received bytes with ASCIIEncoding.  Which has no characters for byte values with the high bit set (0x80-0xff).  So it substitutes it with '?'.  Which has ASCII code 0x3f.  Again, use Read(), not ReadExisting().

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with encoding. You have to add this when you configure your serial port:

SerialPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)